Instrumentation tool for Visual Studio C++ 2017
I have downloaded a CMake-based open-source C++ project. Then I converted that CMake project into a Visual Studio C++ 2017 solution/project.
Now, among all the files, say, I am only interested in AppMain123.cpp.
I want to find out which header files, source files, functions, variables, etc. are needed to build and execute only AppMain123.cpp.
I will keep only those files and delete others.
How can I do that?
Which freeware or open source tool can I use with Visual Studio C++ 2017 to achieve my objective?
